Can $\lim f'(x)/g'(x) = 0$ when $\lim g = +\infty$ and $\lim f$ does not exist?
One of the versions of L'Hôspital's rule given in Rudin (Theorem 5.13) is:

Let $f$, $g$ be differentiable on $(a, b)$ with $g'(x)\ne 0$ and $g(x)\to +\infty$ as $x\to a$. Then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$ if the RHS exists.

I am intrigued by the fact that there is no requirement of $f(x)$ to "blow up" at $a$ as well. Of course, the case when $\lim f$ is finite, it'd be $0$, so let's assume that $f$ has no finite limit at $a$. All the examples I have come across so far also have $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \pm\infty$ as well which is imposed if $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)/g'(x)$ and hence $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)/g(x)$ is nonzero in the above.
Question: Can the assumptions of the above versions of L'Hôspital's rule be satisfied "minimally"? That is, is there an example where $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ does not exist (not even $\pm\infty$), $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = +\infty$ and yet $\lim_{x\to a} f'(x)/g'(x) = 0$?

Note that $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ and $g(x) = 1/x$ don't work (on $(0, 1)$) because although $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)/g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} x\sin(1/x)$ exists, $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)/g'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\cos(1/x)$ does not.

There are lots of examples: $f(x)=\sin \frac{1}{x-a}$ and $g(x)=e^{e^{|\frac{1}{x-a}|}}$ is one such. On the one hand $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f'(x)$ does not exist yet $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does exist and is clearly $0$.The idea for constructing such an example is this: The function $f$ is bounded but oscilates more wildly as $x$ approaches $a$ while $g$ goes very rapidly to $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $a$: In fact, so much so that the equation $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} =0$ is true.

Nice answer, but I liked @julio-es-sui-glace's comment (now weirdly deleted) better for his was simpler (although his had the same spirit as your construction): Take $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ and $g(x) = 1/x^2$ (at $a = 0$).
